# For a massless pulley moving upwards with acceleration, is the upward force equal to the downward force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Imagine a massless and frictionless pulley with two weights hanging either side of the pulley by a massless string.

[Like this except not attached to a ceiling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pulley%20system&biw=1442&bih=722&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=WsVHVMGFLMSt7AaLzIE4&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=ngUKNPqitCbbtM%253A%3B_eV5rAlVafPl7M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimg.webassign.net%252Fuserimages%252F61673%253Fdb%253Dv4net%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.chegg.com%252Fhomework-help%252Fquestions-and-answers%252Fconsider-mass-pulley-system-sketched--pulley-considered-solid-disk-mass-of160-kg-moment-in-q736858%3B206%3B249)

Rather than being fixed to a ceiling, the pulley is being pulled upward by an external force F, with the weights and string still attached.

Due to Newton's 2nd Law,

$\Sigma F_y=F-2T=ma$,

where $T$ is the tension in the string on either side of the pulley and $a$ is the vertical acceleration of the pulley.

Clearly, since there is a net upward force, the pulley itself will accelerate upwards.

But because the $m=0$,

$F-2T=0$.

Does this not then suggest that the pulley has a constant velocity?

Comment: What do you mean by "not attached to a ceiling?" Are you saying that the whole setup is just free-falling straight down? If it's not attached to a ceiling, then what object is exerting the force F on the pulley?

Comment: *Clearly, since there is a net upward force, the pulley itself will accelerate upwards.* Huh? Why doesn't the whole apparatus just drop?

Comment: Someone's pulling the pulley upward by a hook of some sort...

Comment: Quite clear by "a force pulls the pulley upward".

Comment: I see. I edited the question a little and retracted my close vote.

Comment: Good homework question in my opinion. Effort has been put in, and the OP is asking about a conceptual interpretation of their derived equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the equation $F_{net}=ma$, normally we would assume that $F_{net}=0$ implies $a=0$ on the right-hand side. However, for a massless object, we can satisfy the equation by having $F_{net}=0$, $m=0$, and $a\ne0$. In reality, of course, the pulley is not massless, so $m$ is small, $a$ is some nonzero number, and $F_{net}$ is small.

The above reasoning is the justification for the usual assumption that low-mass objects transmit forces unchanged, e.g., that the tension in a rope is the same value throughout the length of the rope.