# Atwood's machines: acceleration of massless pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

I have a question regarding Atwood's machines. Consider the following machine and text accompanying it:

[image: Two pulleys]

> The tension in the short string connected to $m_1$ is $2T$ because there must be zero net force on the massless left pulley, because otherwise it would have infinite acceleration.

My problem is that I don't see why the net force on the left pulley must be zero, since it means that the acceleration of the left pulley must be zero, although it clearly is moving upwards (and thus accelerating) when the mass $m_2$ is accelerating downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "massless pulley" approximation is to make the system easier to understand without having to get into junk about rotational inertia.

Suppose that the pulley isn't massless but has some little mass $\delta m \ll m_1$, and that $m_1$ is hanging from it by another rope.  That other rope will have an extra tension for us to keep track of.  We'll still ignore any rotational inertia in the pulley. Here's the new part of the setup:

[image: Modified Atwood machine]

In that case,
Newton's second law for each of the two masses gives

\begin{align}
\delta m\, a_\delta &= 2T - T_\text{extra} - \delta m\, g
\\
m_1 \, a_1 &= T_\text{extra} - m_1\,g
\end{align}

Your author seems to be taking a counterfactual approach.
The acceleration of the pulley is,

$$
a_\delta = \frac{2T - T_\text{extra}}{\delta m} - g
$$

and in the limit $\delta m \to 0$, this acceleration becomes very large unless $T_\text{extra} \approx 2T$; your author states that this is bad and therefore can't be happening.

My instinct is to *assume* the accelerations are the same and to eliminate the bookkeeping tension in the line connecting your mass to the massless pulley:

\begin{align}
T_\text{extra} &= 2T - \delta m(a_\delta + g) \approx 2T
\\
m_1\,a_1 &= \left(
2T - \delta m\,(a_\delta+g)
\right) - m_1\,g
\\
\delta m\,a_\delta + m_1 a_1 &= 2T - (\delta m + m_1)g
\\
\widetilde m_1\,a &= 2T - \widetilde m_1\,g
\tag1
\end{align}

Since $\delta m \ll m_1$, there's not very much difference between $m_1$ and $\widetilde m_1 = m_1 + \delta m$, and the upward force on the latter is $2T$.
The final line (1) encodes the statement that your author makes, that the upward force on $m_1$ is $2T$, and that approximation gets better in the limit that $\delta m$ is very small.

Comment: Thanks! Your line of reasoning helped me much more than that of the author. Maybe the thing that you could add is that zero net force on a massless object doesn't mean zero acceleration, as I just now read [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142577/for-a-massless-pulley-moving-upwards-with-acceleration-is-the-upward-force-equa), as I originally assumed and which was part of my question.

Comment: Something I now don't understand: Why would you have to think about rotation if the net torque on the pulley is already zero (as T is the same at the left and the right of the pulley)?

Comment: If the pulley is "rolling up" the left rope, like a yo-yo, then it is not an ideal pulley and the two tensions cannot be the same. There is a straightforward relationship between the radius of the pulley, its angular acceleration, and the linear acceleration of its center, and another relationship between the angular acceleration, the torque on the pulley, and the pulley's moment of inertia. All this extra complexity vanishes if the moment of inertia for the pulley vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the pulleys are thought to be massless, the acceleration for the
>   left pulley is set to be zero.

This sentence does not make much sense and is probably a misinterpreted version of some other statement.

The condition that the pulleys are weightless means that the tension of the string on both sides of each pulley (and therefore, everywhere) is the same, which simplifies the equations. It is so because the torque required to spin up weightless pulleys, as the system accelerates, is zero.

Updating the answer after the question has been modified.

If the net force on the left pulley was not zero, then its vertical acceleration, $a=F/m_{pulley}$, would be infinite, since $F\ne 0$, while $m_{pulley}=0$.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand a certain statement. I reformulated my question to include the quote that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If m2 is moving, there is no possible way that the block on the left can not be moving, unless the string can be stretched.

The assumptions for the question don't make sense to me unless you are being asked to solve for the mass of m2 as a multiple of m1, such that its in static equilibrium.

Comment: I reformulated my question, please have another look.